# Pass a string value to a range object

Tags: excel, vba

Simple question I need a hand on: How do I pass a string into a range object in Excel VBA?

Example code:

```
Dim Trange As Range
Dim sAddress As String
Sub example
sAddress = "Output Averages!$C$23:$C$" & (23 + total)
Set Trange = Range(sAddress)
End Sub
```

**Error Received:** Method 'Range' of object _Global failed. Run time error 1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a very minor mistake. You need to enclose the sheet name in "'", like:

```
sAddress = "'Output Averages'!$C$23:$C$" & (23 + total)
```